# How do I draw an image from drawable onto an imageview with Canvas - Android

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, drawable

I have an activity which has an `ImageView` in it. What I want to do is be able to draw where the user touches that `Imageview` with an image from the drawable folder. I've read that the best way is to use Canvas, but I'm not sure where and how I integrate the `onDraw` method with the `onTouchListener`. This is what I have so far:

```
public class Main extends Activity
{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
      final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

      //Bitmap
      Bitmap viewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(viewBitmap);
      image.draw(canvas);

      image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
      {
         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
         {
            textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " + String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
            return false;
         }
      });
   }
}
```

So what I want to do is when the user touches the `ImageView`, an image will be drawn exactly where he touched it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to subclass `ImageView` in order to override its `onDraw()` method.  By doing so, you can also to the custom touch handling in `onTouchEvent()` instead of attaching a listener.  This is not a complete example, but something like the following:

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

    private ArrayList<Point) mTouches;
    private Bitmap mMarker;

    //Java constructor
    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    //XML constructor
    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mTouches = new ArrayList<Point>();
        mMarker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.my_marker_image);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //Capture a reference to each touch for drawing
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            mTouches.add( new Point(event.getX(), event.getY()) );
            return true;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        //Let the image be drawn first
        super.onDraw(c);

        //Draw your custom points here
        Paint paint = new Paint();            
        for(Point p : mTouches) {
            c.drawBitmap(mMarker, p.x, p.y, paint);
        }
    }

}
```

HTH!

Comment: Thank you for your response. Where in your example do you set the Canvas to be imageView2? (The imageview I want to draw on)

Comment: To be more clear, this custom class takes the place of imageView2 in your existing layout.  The image contents of the ImageView and the individual touch points are drawn together on the same Canvas (the touch markers drawn over the image), within the bounds of the ImageView.

Comment: I've tried get your code working with my activity, but all I get is my original Imageview and it does not do anything when I touch it. Is there anything that I need to declare in the onCreate method for when the activity starts. I shouldn't need the onTouchListener since I have the onTouchEvent below, right?

Comment: Correct, make sure there are not OnTouchListeners attached to this view or they might steal the touches, and make sure that you actually have an instance of your new custom class in the layout, and not a plain vanilla ImageView.

Comment: I removed the onTouchListener so I only have the onTouchEvent which is in the subclass, I made a custom Imageview in the xml and declared it in the layout, but it's still not doing anything. It's like the onTouchEvent doesn't occur. Am I missing something? Is there something specific that I have to declare in the onCreate method so this works?

Comment: Also, It's giving me an error where you do "mTouches.add(new Point(event.getX(), event.getY()); Seems like when you declare mTouches = new ArrayList<Point>(); that it's missing the parameters. How can I fix this?

Comment: You're getting an error because the x/y values are floats, and that constructor takes an int.  As I mentioned, I didn't provide a completed example, just some pseudocode to get you headed in the right direction.  There is nothing you need to do to activate touch event detection.  Make sure that none of the other parent/sibling views in the hierarchy views are capturing/intercepting the touch as well.

Comment: I finally got this to work. Thank you for your example and heading me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I edited your class like this and it works for me

```
public class MyImageView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView {
    
    private Bitmap mMarker;
    private Path mPath,  circlePath ;
    private Paint  paint, circlePaint;

    private Canvas mCanvas;

    //Java constructor
    public MyImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();

    }

    //XML constructor
    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mTouches = new ArrayList<Point>();

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(12);

        mPath = new Path();
        Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePath = new Path();
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        mMarker = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mMarker);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;

            circlePath.reset();
            circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        circlePath.reset();
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath,  paint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        //Let the image be drawn first
        super.onDraw(c);

            c.drawBitmap(mMarker, 0, 0, paint);
        c.drawPath( mPath,  paint);
        c.drawPath( circlePath,  circlePaint);
      
    }

}
```